# How can my FixedSingle .Net Userform still get maximized sometimes

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I've got a Windows Forms application running on a virtual server.
A few people can connect to this server via Remote Desktop to check progress/status.

The userform should have only one size which shouldn't change.
Therefore the FormBorderStyle is set to FixedSingle and the Maximize box is disabled.
But still sometimes the form is shown as maximized somehow.
Since the Maximize button is disabled, there's no way return to the old size.

I've asked all people with access and no one explicitly tries to maximize it.
It 'just happens' (of course it doesn't, but it seems so).

The application can be minimized to tray when the Minimize Box is clicked.
It can then be restored by double clicking the icon from the system tray.
WindowState will then be set to FormWindowState.Normal.

Can anybody think of a way the userform still gets maximized?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure how it could be getting maximized, but something to try would be handling the Forms resize event and reset the width/height and FormWindowState. Possible that RDP resizes window size based on who accesses the server (users screen resolution).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will implement that.
It's unfortunate that I can't test it, but time will tell.